# 2 6-sided die are rolled. What is the probability that their faces are different?

Tags: probability, dice

I thought it was:

$$
\frac{1}{6}\frac{5}{6} = \frac{5}{36}
$$

since the first die has one number out of $6$, and the second die has to be the other $5$.

But I'm not exactly sure if that's right.

Answer (score 5):

No.

*No matter the outcome of the first die*, the second die has a $1$ in $6$ chance of matching that. So, the probability of being different is $5$ out of $6$.